# Need help Understanding Gitk and Left-Most branch

Tags: git, gitk

Let's say I have 2 branches. Master and dev. I run the following:

```
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

This occurs when changes on the master branch need to be merged into the dev branch (rare...) However, after doing this (and in other seemingly random scenarios) gitk shows:

```
. - Dev
| \. - Master
|  |
|  . Commit 2
|  |
| /
. - Commit 1
```

How can I make the master branch always be the left-most displayed branch?

Comment: The most recent tip commit will be shown as the tip of the leftmost branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need at least to checkout master again.

Or to merge dev back into master (which would fast-forward master to dev)

gitk shows the first parent chains as straight lines in the graph... which has [been criticized before](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/first-parent-commit-graph-layout-and-pull-merge-direction-td7586671.html).